# Moving a span element from one div to another with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to move (on page load) the `<span>votes</span>` part at the bottom and place it inside the `.rating-result` div:

```
<div class="topic-like-count average">
 <h4>
  <div style="display: none">UN:F [1.9.10_1130]</div>
  <div class="thumblock ">
   <span class="rating-result">
     <div id="gdsr_thumb_text_43_a" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumbtext">0</div>
  </span>
  <div class="ratingtext ">
  </div>
  <div class="raterclear"></div>
  </div>
 </h4>
<span>votes</span>
</div>
```

So that the final result looks like this:

```
<div class="topic-like-count average">
 <h4>
  <div style="display: none">UN:F [1.9.10_1130]</div>
  <div class="thumblock ">
   <span class="rating-result">
     <div id="gdsr_thumb_text_43_a" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumbtext">0</div>
     <span>votes</span>
  </span>
  <div class="ratingtext ">
  </div>
  <div class="raterclear"></div>
  </div>
 </h4>
</div>
```

How to accomplish that with jQuery?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that where is more than one `.topic-like-count` div (for example):

```
<div class="topic-like-count good">
 <h4>
  <div style="display: none">UN:F [1.9.10_1130]</div>
  <div class="thumblock ">
   <span class="rating-result">
     <div id="gdsr_thumb_text_43_a" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumbtext">1</div>
  </span>
  <div class="ratingtext ">
  </div>
  <div class="raterclear"></div>
  </div>
 </h4>
<span>votes</span>
</div>

<div class="topic-like-count average">
 <h4>
  <div style="display: none">UN:F [1.9.10_1130]</div>
  <div class="thumblock ">
   <span class="rating-result">
     <div id="gdsr_thumb_text_43_a" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumbtext">0</div>
  </span>
  <div class="ratingtext ">
  </div>
  <div class="raterclear"></div>
  </div>
 </h4>
<span>votes</span>
</div>
```

(I think I need to use `($this)` somewhere)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$span=$("#votes").clone();
$("#votes").remove();
$("#gdsr_thumb_text_43_a").append($span);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dc47b/4/

**EDIT**

```
function doIt(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $span=$("#votes").clone();
    $("#votes").remove();
    $("#gdsr_thumb_text_43_a").append($span);

    }, 1000);
}


window.onload = function() {
     doIt();

   };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dc47b/5/

**yet another edit**

```
$(".topic-like-count").each(function(){

$span=$(this).find(".vote").clone();
    $(this).find(".vote").remove();
    $(this).find("#gdsr_thumb_text_43_a").append($span);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BG7HC/1/

and

http://jsfiddle.net/dc47b/6/

Comment: erm wouldn't $(function(... or $(document).ready... be better than a timeout?

Comment: the setTimeout function is just so that the effect is been seen that originally the span is positioned at the end and then placed inside the intended div

Comment: ah, looks like part of the solution

Comment: Why are you doing a .clone() and then .remove()? Why not just move it with .appendTo()?

Comment: @Aknosis that didn't occured to me

Comment: @3nigma Hey thanks, but I forgot to mention taht there are a lot of `.topic-like-count` divs. I think your code is just for one div.

Comment: jus made a little change to your markup, i.e. added a `class="vote"` to your `span`

Comment: @Aknosis: nice, I always thought the append() and appendTo() methods required you to detach the element first.

Comment: @rkw i still think that way may you could verify with a fiddle `:)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.topic-like-count > span').appendTo('.rating-result');
```

There is no point in cloning, you are just wasting cycles.

Comment: The purpose of using > span is you target the child that is a direct descendant of .topic-like-count, you could also do .children('span') and a ton of other selectors.

Comment: I have more than one `.topic-like-count` div. Is this code working every `.topic-like-count` div which has a span element inside?

Comment: I tried your code and is appending all the voting text in all the divs (around 15).

Answer (score 1):

Use the appendTo keyword.

Check out the SO answer [How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/jquery-how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element).

Also you could I guess use clone and then remove the original

To select the actual span in question use something like;

```
$(".topic-like-count:last-child")
```

Comment: hey please check my edit. There are more .topic-like-count divs. I need the code to just move the child span of its own div. Otherwise all 'votes' texts will appear every div.

Comment: take a look at the .each jQuery keyword in that case and itterate thru each of the div applying the same code to each

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.topic-like-count').delegate('span.votes', 'click', function() {
    $('span.rating-result').append($(this));
});
```

Use delegates, it has a great way of sectioning off logic.

The above code translates to:

- on every 'div' with 'topic-like-count' class..  (*)
- listen to see if a 'span' object with 'votes' class..  (**)
- causes a 'click' event.
- when that happens, find the 'span' with a 'rating-result' class w/i (*)..
- and add (**) after detaching it from it's original spot

Answer (score 0):

I used `appendTo` jquery function for easiest way to moving content

```
$mgdiv=$(".your_div_name");
$($mgdiv).appendTo(".target_div_name");
```