# How can I move all divs before an element to after it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a div that I've selected in jQuery and it has div's preceding it. I want to select all of them, copy them to AFTER the selected div and delete them from their original location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var selected = $('#selected');
selected
    .prevAll()
    .insertAfter(selected);
```

Comment: Will this delete the previous ones?

Comment: @Shamoon - yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/jquery-how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to move the selected div to the front of the others?

```
$('#selected_div').insertBefore($('#selected_div').siblings('div:first'));
```