# How to change order of html tag by using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to do bellow step by using jquery.
Does anyone know great solution?

1. Get DOM object of "ul" element.

   ```
   <ul id="rows">
       <li class="row1">
           <a class="row1-1" href="/kensaku2/Page1" title="page1">
           2011/11/16</a>
       </li>
       <li class="row2">
           <a class="row1-2" href="/kensaku2/Page2" title="page2">
           2011/11/15</a>
       </li>
       <li class="row3">
           <a class="row1-3" href="/kensaku2/Page3" title="page3">
           2011/12/21</a>
       </li>
       <li class="row4">
           <a class="row1-4" href="/kensaku2/Page4" title="page4">
           2011/12/05</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Find "li" element that has "a" element's content equals '2011/12/21'. (This is "row3" li element.)
3. Move the "li" element to the head. (also see bellow code.)

   ```
   <ul id="rows">
       <li class="row3">
           <a class="row1-3" href="/kensaku2/Page3" title="page3">
           2011/12/21</a>
       </li>

       <li class="row1">
           <a class="row1-1" href="/kensaku2/Page1" title="page1">
           2011/11/16</a>
       </li>
       <li class="row2">
           <a class="row1-2" href="/kensaku2/Page2" title="page2">
           2011/11/15</a>
       </li>
       <li class="row4">
           <a class="row1-4" href="/kensaku2/Page4" title="page4">
           2011/12/05</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
   ```

I already know how to get DOM object of "ul" element like this.

```
    $("#rows").get(0)
```

But I don't know step 2 and 3.
So, I'd like to ask experts.

Comment: Moving: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/jquery-how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element

Comment: For finding an element containing a value: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will select the `a` element whose text is "2011/12/21" and move the parent `li` as first child:

```
$('#rows a:contains("2011/12/21")').parent().prependTo('#rows');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Pzdk4/)

Comment: Nice answer using the `:contains` pseudo-selector. I believe it's more performative than `.filter()`.

Comment: Agreed, and this will probably solve the problem nicely. However, it should be pointed out that this will not do if an *exact* match is what OP is after.

Comment: Indeed, `2011/12/21 BC` would also be catched, although looking at the sample markup, it seems it sticks to YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: It's really unbelievable !! It worked. Thanks so much! I'm a beginner of jquery. Please give me another solution if you have. I'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#rows li").filter(function() {

    // trimming is needed in this case, it seems
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "2011/12/21";
}).prependTo("#rows");
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/EyQg8/)

Comment: @Adam Rackis - No need, since `.text()` will only extract the plain text, ignoring the markup, so it doesn't really matter in this instance.

Comment: No kidding - I didn't know that ... makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#rows li a").filter(function(){return $(this).text()=='2011/12/21'})
```

this will select the desired value move it where ever you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$("#rows li a:contains('2011/12/21')").parent().prependTo("#rows");
```

This will use a selector to find the `<a>` tag that contains the desired text, get its parent and then prepend that to the #rows object.  Preprend means to append it as a child, but make it the first child.

You can see a demo work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7MRXs/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do more sorting based on the dates and not only the content of that single element you describe, you might want to use an element sorting plugin like this one:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

It will work like this (untested):

```
$('li').sortElements(function(a, b){
    var dateA = parseInt($(a).find('a').text().replace('/', ''), 10);
    var dateB = parseInt($(b).find('a').text().replace('/', ''), 10);

    return dateA <= dateB ? -1 : 1; // you might want to switch this one
});
```