# Move div to other parent, so it inherits from that parent

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

I basically want to reassign a parent to my DIV:

```
<DIV id='main'>
   <DIV id='child'>

   </DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV id='surrogate'>
</DIV>
```

So i want child to be child of surrogate.

I tried:

```
var $a = $('#child');
var contents = $a.contents();
$a.remove();
$('#surrogate').append('<p>' + contents + '</p>');
```

But it will just output: [object Object]

Is there a better/working way to just reassign a parent to a whole tree of elements, without reading the content copying or cloning it?
Well, maybe cloning works, but I'd rather just move it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the html from inside child which returns a string so you can concatenate it the way you are doing

```
var $a = $('#child');
$('#surrogate').append('<p>' + $a.html() + '</p>');

$a.remove();
```

contents() is returning a jQuery object and you can't concatenate an object and string

Comment: +2, But OP: be careful that the `child` doesn't already contain a `<p>` that will get wrapped with another `<p>` when you append it to the surrogate div (i.e., `$a.html() == '<p>Old content of child div.</p>';`).