# Remove div and append after another div

Tags: jquery, append, removeclass

I would like to rearrange the order of my divs.

This is my structure here:

```
  <div class="span8 inner-left" style="clear:both;">
    <div class="span3" style="text-align:right;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="moreread" class="span4 inner-left"></div>
```

This is what I would like my outcome to be:

```
   <div class="span8 inner-left" style="clear:both;">
     <div class="span3" style="text-align:right;"></div>
     <div id="moreread" class="span4 inner-left"></div>
  </div>
```

This does not work:

```
$(this).find('#moreread').after(".span3");
```

Comment: Probably duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `appendTo` method:

```
$('#moreread').appendTo('.span8');
```

Please note that your markup is invalid, you should close your div tags.

Comment: oops, that works but it adds it before '.span3' I need to add it after

Answer (score 2):

You want to either `.insertAfter('.span3')`, or `.appendTo('.span8')`

The former will always put it directly after `.span3`, whereas the latter will always make it the last child of `.span8` - in this case the two being equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="span8 inner-left" style="clear:both;">
    A
    <div class="span3" style="text-align:right;">B</div>
</div>
<div id="moreread" class="span4 inner-left">C</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#moreread').insertAfter('.span3');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/WD976/1/