# jQuery move multiple DOM elements into other elements using their classes (not IDs)

Tags: jquery, class, dom, element, move

I'm working on a page with multiple blog articles and due to constraints of the current platform/template can't move the comment count in the HTML.

I would like to move the .reaction-count elements from one part of each article into another part.

I've read the solutions on this thread: [How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element) but I'm still not sure how to translate that into what I need.

Here's what I've tried so far. It's not quite working since it moves all the .reaction-count elements into all the .post-title elements instead of just the .reaction-count for that particular article.

One attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/DanEvans/jbgC4

Another attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/DanEvans/jbgC4/5/

Here's some simplified example HTML that mimics the situation:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <h2 class="post-title">
        <a href="#">Post #1</a>
    </h2>

    <p>Lots of other text and elements</p>

    <span class="reaction-count">
        <br><a href="#">Post #1 Comments</a>
    </span>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="entry-content">
    <h2 class="post-title">
        <a href="#">Post #2</a>
    </h2>

    <p>Lots of other text and elements</p>

    <span class="reaction-count">
        <br><a href="#">Post #2 Comments</a>
    </span>
</div>​
```

One of the first things I tried:

```
$('.reaction-count').appendTo('.post-title');​
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just trying to move the reaction counts into the post-title of the same entry content..

```
$('.reaction-count').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.post-title').append($(this));
});  ​  ​
```

(My traversing was wrong).

Would move the reaction-count into the post title within it's parent entry-content on an individual basis.

[Fiddle with your CSS included](http://jsfiddle.net/ehFH5/)

Comment: I ended up changing **parent()** to **parents('.entry-content')** before using it on the live site since there are some other elements in play