# How to display two tr's with its id in the same row by its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with its tr tags. I want to display two tr tags side by side by its class. How can i able to do that using jquery.

```
<table>
   <tr class='1'>
     <td>First</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='1'>
      <td>second</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='2'>
       <td>third</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='3'>
       <td>fourth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='3'>
       <td>fifth</td>
   </tr>  
</table>
```

Then in the output i want to display

```
 First     Second
 Third
 Fourth    Fifth
```

I want to set those dynamically how can i do that using jquery or javascript. I want to use the class declared for the tr tag. I know want to use `<td>` tag for that.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: id is unique! you need to use class or different name

Comment: You can't use same ids for different elements.

Comment: But...rows are rows. Why would you deliberately write html with rows that don't have the right format and then change it with JS? (And I guess it's obligatory for me to point out that ID should be unique.)

Comment: If you use class say class="one", class="two" and so on. You can use this to print the text.  $('.one').each(function(){

    $(this).text();

});  and so on

Comment: I don't knoe the class exactly it will come dynamically from the database but it will be numbers `1,2......`

Comment: Don't use a `table` if you don't want it to behave like a table, period.

Comment: what's the reasoning behind not styling these using CSS?

Comment: How can i style with css for the classes

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first way that came to mind:

```
var $tds = $("td");      // get all the tds
[].reverse.call($tds);   // reverse the order so we can easily loop backwards

$tds.each(function() {
    var $parentRow = $(this).parent(),
        // find the first row with the same class that isn't this row
        $firstTrSameClass = $("tr").filter("." +$parentRow.attr("class"))
                                   .not($parentRow).first();
    if ($firstTrSameClass.length > 0) { // if there is such a row
        $firstTrSameClass.append(this); // move the td
        $parentRow.remove();            // delete the original row
    }   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pgcdq/

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see a use case here but I guess the eaisiest would be to create new rows and move cells to them. You will find information on moving elements here:
[How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)