# Append partial html code jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-append

I am building an html page and I need to add html code from one div to another dinamically.

This is my first div:

```
<div id="placeHolder" style="display:none">
    <div id="1">....</div>
    <div id="2">....</div>  
    <div id="3">....</div>      
</div>
```

And I want to add the divs with the id 1, 2 and 3 to another div(#mainDiv) but not all at once.

Is there a way to add partial html code with jquery ? I know theres a function called append but what I dont know if it is suitable for this type of ocasion..

Thanks

Comment: what have you done so far? Some event/ code example would be helpful

Comment: I just know that if I do $('#mainDiv').append('#placeHolder').html()); it will grab all the divs and put them inside the mainDiv..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer to this question by searching stackoverflow. I guess you are looking for the appendTo function like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element). So, yes, you are right, appendTo is a good solution I think :-)

Answer (score 1):

Say for instance you want to move them from the second div to the first:

```
<div id="newPlace">
</div>

<div id="placeHolder">
  <div id="1">....</div>
  <div id="2">....</div>
  <div id="3">....</div>
</div>
```

Then you can select elements with jQuery, copy them to the other place with append, and remove them from there original place:

```
$("#placeHolder div").appendTo("#newPlace").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div id="placeHolder" style="display:none">
    <div id="1" onclick="change(this)">....</div>
    <div id="2" onclick="change(this)">....</div>  
    <div id="3" onclick="change(this)">....</div>      
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function change(element) {
    if ($(element).attr('id') === 1) {
        $('#mainDiv').append($(element).html());
    } ...
    // AND THE SAME FOR EACH DIV. IF YOU DON'T HAVE TOO MUCH, THIS CAN BE A WAY
}
```

With an `onclick` on your divs or whatever event you want to use to trigger this, you can use this function to change the content of your `mainDiv` depending on which element is selected, identified by `id` property.

If you are setting your divs data without any event throwed in your divs, you just have to add the function that I posted where you want to use it. Like here:

```
$(function() {
    //SOME STUFF
    $('#mainDiv').append($('#1').html()); //OR
    $('#mainDiv').append($('#2').html()); //OR
    $('#mainDiv').append($('#3').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is what you want

use append()

try this

```
$(function(){
  $('#mainDiv').append($('#1')); //to append div with id 1
  $('#mainDiv').append($('#2'));

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HtTXB/)

Comment: why append().html() ? what is the html() useful vor?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you mean by adding html cod once at a time ...

Lets say you have a new div to add html code:

```
<div id="placeHolder" style="display:none">
    <div id="1">....</div>
    <div id="2">....</div>  
    <div id="3">....</div>      
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#placeHolder').children().each(function (){
    $('.result').append(this);
    // do some other things
  });
});
```

Using children() to extract all the children div in the target div, and each() to literate through them.

http://jsfiddle.net/nvQG8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just store it in a string var and append it after your loop.