# How do I position a div sticking on top of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have 2 types of divs

```
<div class="target_div" id="t1">  </div>
<div class="target_div" id="t2">  </div>
<div class="target_div" id="t3">  </div>
<div class="target_div" id="t4">  </div>


<div class="child_div" id="c1">  </div>
<div class="child_div" id="c2">  </div>
<div class="child_div" id="c3">  </div>
<div class="child_div" id="c4">  </div>
```

Using Jquery , say I want to position c1 over t1 , so that their top left corners match always , how do I go about doing this ? I want c1 to stick to t1 no matter what ... page resizing , scrolling.. in all cases .

I am creating a card game , and I want to drag drop and place the cards from the footer and place in the divs numbered 1-13 . Hence the question.

In the picture , t1,t2... etc are the divs with numbers 1-13 . c1,c2 etc are the cards lying on the footer.

Comment: on drag drop, make the c1 child of t1... make t1 position:relative and  c1 position:absolute with top:0 and left:0

Answer (score 0):

Just set your card to position absolute with CSS and then use this script :

```
var offset = $('#t1').offset() //example
$('#c1').css({
    'top' : offset.top,
    'left' : offset.left
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add `position:relative;` to the `target_div` class.

when you'r droping a `child_div` in `target_div`, move the `child_div` element to be a direct child of `target_div` (DOM manipulation is very easy using JavaScript & JQuery [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)), then add `position:absolute; top:0; left:0;` to the specific `child_div` being moved.