# Setting the InnerHTML for a div with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a div that holds many buttons that gets created dynamically.
By using the following:

```
var s = document.getElementById("CancelColumn").innerHTML;
s = s+ "<input class=\"CancelButt\" type=\"button\" value=\"X\" onclick=\"deleteRow(\""+value+"\",this)\">" ;
document.getElementById("CancelColumn").innerHTML = s;
```

The problem however is that in firefox the html is showing up as this:

```
<input class="CancelButt" type="button" SomeString",this)"="" onclick="deleteRow(" value="X"></input>
```

where the value is "SomeString".

In chrome it is a bit different though. The string has an extra space and the tag doesn't seem to be working correctly.
Here it is:

I want it to show the following:

Where "this" is the button that is calling the function.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but you should improve your code anyway. Here's an example of improved code.

```
var element = document.getElementById('CancelColumn');
    newInput = document.createElement('input');

newInput.type = 'button';
newInput.value = 'X';
newInput.className = 'CancelButt';
newInput.onclick = deleteRow.bind(null, value, newInput); // whatever value is?

element.appendChild(newInput);
```

It's a lot cleaner and readable, I'm not surprised you're facing problems with the code you have.

Comment: Thanks, Had no idea I could do this.

Comment: Aren't you overwriting the invocation context with the `null` parameter?

Comment: @tewathia if i didn't set `null`, the value would be `newInput` so it seems pointless to use `this` and `newInput` to access the element. of course you can change `null` to `newInput`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like such an inelegant way of doing it

Why not try this?

```
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.setAttribute('class', 'CancelButt');
inp.setAttribute('type', 'button');
inp.setAttribute('value', 'X');
inp.onclick = deleteRow.bind(inp, 2, inp); // you don't really need to pass the 'this' value to the deleteRow function though
```

Then you can just append the `inp` to your `#CancelColumn`

Comment: rethink your `onclick`

Comment: @connorspiracist Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out(although it was the OP's `onclick` I was just making the code readable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
s = s+ "<input class='CancelButt' type='button' value='X' onclick='deleteRow('"+value+"',this)'>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `s = s+ "<input class=\"CancelButt\" type=\"button\" value=\"X\" onclick=\"deleteRow(\""+value+"\",this)\">" ;` as `s = s+ "<input class='CancelButt' type=
'button' value='x' onclick='deleteRow('+value+',this)\'">" ;`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
s = s +  "<input class='CancelButt' type='button' value='X'
             onclick='deleteRow("+value+",this)'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly...
Do you want to have a div which you dynamically populate with buttons and when you click any of those buttons, they will move to another div?

In that case, I think your question is similar to this question - [How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

From Alejandro Illecas answer:

> **MOVE:**
>
> jQuery("#NodesToMove").detach().appendTo('#DestinationContainerNode')
>
> **COPY:**
>
> jQuery("#NodesToMove").appendTo('#DestinationContainerNode')
>
> **note** .detach() use. When copy be careful do not duplicate id's.

---

### JSFiddle

I modified his solution in this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/8VrdE/)** in which you can see that you don't need a very cumbersome script to manage a move of an element.

### jQuery

```
function moveButton(elem){
   if( $(elem).parent().attr("id") == "nonSelected" ){
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#selected');
   }
   else{
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#nonSelected'); 
   }
}
```

### HTML

As you can see here, you can use different kinds of elements as well...

```
<div id="nonSelected">

   <!-- TWO INPUT TAGS --> 
   <input id="btnDefault" onclick="moveButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Default" />
   <input id="btnPrimary" onclick="moveButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Primary" />

   <!-- THREE BUTTON TAGS -->
   <button id="btnDanger" onclick="moveButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
   <button id="btnWarning" onclick="moveButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
   <button id="btnSuccess" onclick="moveButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

</div>


<div id="selected">

</div>
```