# How many ways do I have to move element A to element B and which they are

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been playing around with Jquery but I got stuck in this point and to solve it I have this doubt.

I would like to put all these anchor elements inside a div that I want to create.

```
<td class="cont-mod-none-options" valign="top" align="right">
    <a href="test1">copy</a>
    <a href="test2">cut</a>
    <a href="test3">
        <img src="/images/edit.png" width="28" height="12" border="0">
    </a>
    <a href="test4">
        <img src="/images/pic.png" width="12" height="12" border="0">
    </a>
</td>
```

Is there any way to create a div element and put all these elements inside that div?
Like this:

```
<td class="cont-mod-none-options" valign="top" align="right">
    <div>
         <a href="test1">copy</a>
         <a href="test2">cut</a>
         <a href="test3">
            <img src="/images/edit.png" width="28" height="12" border="0">
         </a>
         <a href="test4">
            <img src="/images/pic.png" width="12" height="12" border="0">
          </a>
    </div>
 </td>
```

So, how many possibilities do I have to move that?

Comment: are you looking for a number? 4?

Comment: *cough* http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move an element into another element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Comment: Casey I found this post it didnt helped me.

Comment: Maybe html append... with jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
var $a = $("td").children();
$("td").append($("<div />").append($a));
```

I am not 100% sure what you mean about possibilities.  There are more than a few ways to accomplish it.  This is just one quick way.

Essentially you create a selector to point at what you want moved, and then append it to where you need it.

Fiddle with your example:  http://jsfiddle.net/kt4F2/

```
var $a = $("td").children();
$("td").append($("<div />").append($a));
```

An alternate:  http://jsfiddle.net/w9GCh/

the second uses `$.wrapAll()`

```
$("td").children().wrapAll("<div />");
```

Comment: @dfsq No, im creating a div tag which is appended to td with its content being $a.  I just put it all on the same line.  I could easily just say:   `var $a = ..; var $div=$("<div />");  $div.append($a); $("td").append($div);`

Comment: Fallen, is there any way using wrapAll()?

Comment: Yes,  If you look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/w9GCh/ It shows.  If you inspect the Dom of the item, it does the exact same thing in 1 line that i wrote in 2. :)