# CSS: How to move contents of one div into another one

Tags: css

I'm moddifiyng a webpage through css styles and I got stuck trying to join two divs.

```
<div class="grid_0">
 <div class="grid_0">
  <div class="wallpaper" itemtype="xyz""></div>
  <div class="wallpaper" itemtype="xyz""></div>
  <div class="wallpaper" itemtype="xyz""></div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="grid_0"></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="grid_0">
  <div class="wallpaper" itemtype="xyz""></div>
  <div class="wallpaper" itemtype="xyz""></div>
  <div class="wallpaper" itemtype="xyz""></div>
 </div>
```

The main container has a flex property (because I want the width of the page to flex with different display resolutions “out there”) and 100% width.

I want to merge the contents of FIRST and LAST **grid_0 divs**, but between them lay three other divs: two spacers and an add box (the one in the middle).
Notice that the div in the middle (the add box) shares the same ID with the ones I want to merge.

Hiding the two spacers and the add box (using the :nth-child property) didn't do the trick..

[Here's a “diagram” that shows the layout.](http://h64i.imgup.net/Untitled-1dfc5.jpg)

How can I move the three thumbs in the **last** grid_0 **into the first** grid_0 through CSS?

**EDIT:**
I suspect this isn't doable through CSS..
I might need to use a java script.

Comment: What do you mean, you want to merge?

Comment: can you provide us the entire markup? how about a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not manipulate the DOM with CSS, you need JS or something similar. 
You will need to try something like this:

```
$("#id-of-first-element").append( $("#id-of-last-element") );
$("#id-of-last-element").html('');
```

Comment: Yes, i've done that already. I found it here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)
Thank You.

Comment: Any solution without jQuery?