# How to move an element into another one using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to move an element into another one so a css `:hover` would work.

```
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item"> //move into here </li>
</ul>

<div class="tomove">...</div>
```

'tomove' is `display:none;`

`menu-item:hover` makes 'tomove' `display:block;`

I need this to work with css `:hover` and be moved into a `<li>` item

Comment: `$('.tomove').appendTo('#menu-item')`

Comment: you can use like `$( ".tomove" ).detach().appendTo('#menu-item')`

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move an element into another element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to move element in DOM

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

**Demo**

```js
$('.tomove').appendTo('#menu-item');
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  color: green;
}
#menu-item:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item">//move into here</li>
</ul>

<div class="tomove">Move me There</div>
```