# Avoid some HTML element from JS function with HTML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I would like to avoid some HTML element from a JS function with HTML data, or tag element. Is it possible or not?

Thanks! :D

Comment: Which elements do you want to avoid and why ?

Comment: a preview of some of the code you think off with this question might help us give you a more correct answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move an element into another element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery to select and exclude things from the result.

```
$( ".some_class" ).not( "some_element" );
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! :D

Comment: I'll do, but I need to wait 10 minutes (2 left) ^^'