# How to Move an element in a div into another div on trigger of an event using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id='one'>
<div id='oneone'>
</div>
</div>
<div id='two'>
</div>
```

On click of a button i want div with id='oneone' in div with id='two'

```
 <div id='one'>
    </div>
    <div id='two'>
    <div id='oneone'>
    </div>
    </div>
```

How do i achieve this using JavaScript , 
Actually instead of div as a child element i want it to work for images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move an element into another element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Comment: Thank you very much haxxxton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have jQuery in your project, you can use the below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btnMove").click(function(){
  
    var $div = $("#oneone");    
    $("#two").append($div);   
    
  });
});
```

```css
#one{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  }

#two{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  }

#oneone{
  background-color:silver;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='one'>
  <div id='oneone'>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='two'>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnMove" value="Move container">
```

Using native JavaScript:

```js
function onMoveButtonClick(){
 var divTobeMoved = document.getElementById("oneone"),
     sourceDiv = document.getElementById("one"),
     targetDiv = document.getElementById("two");

  if(sourceDiv.querySelector("#oneone") != null) {
      sourceDiv.removeChild(divTobeMoved);
      targetDiv.appendChild(divTobeMoved);
   }
 
  }
```

```css
#one{
      border: 1px solid blue;
      height: 50px;
      width: 200px;
      }

    #two{
      border: 1px solid green;
      height: 50px;
      width: 200px;
      }

    #oneone{
      background-color:silver;
      height: 30px;
      width: 200px;
      }
```

```html
<div id='one'>
      <div id='oneone'>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='two'>
    </div>
<input type="button" onclick="onMoveButtonClick()" value="Move">
```

Comment: I want it using JavaScript only

Comment: @davidraj - may be you should be clear on the question what exactly you are trying to achieve. Give the image id instead of div id and the above code should work

Comment: Ok will check and get back to you thanks for answering and sorry for not being specific

Comment: Why use `innerHTML` when you already have a node? Just use `appendChild` instead. Using `innerHTML` will not move the node, it will delete it from one place and make a new one elsewhere, which can have other side-effects (for example, any event handlers would not survive). It will also change the identity of the node, which might matter if you use the node's identity elsewhere in code.

Comment: @Amadan - thats right, will update my code. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('one');
var oneone = document.getElementById('oneone');
var two = document.getElementById('two');
two.appendChild(parent.removeChild(oneone));
```

removeChild returns the deleted node, use its reference to append at desired place.
 Wrap it in a function and call it from any event but make sure DOM is loaded before calling this piece of code.