# I need to move images from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html structure. I want the other field items to be together with the others.

```
<div class="secondary-images">
  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group1">
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group2">
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want this.

```
<div class="secondary-images">
  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group1">
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
    <div class="field__item"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group2">

  </div>
</div>
```

How do i move the elements.
I tried this but with no luck.

```
var $element = $('.secondary-images > .group2').detach();
$('.secondary-images > .group1').append($element);
```

Comment: You have **what** structure?

Comment: why not just append on the second div and then remove from the first div? update: due to how your structure is, you will get the whole .group2 div inside the group1 div, not just the content. You could do it iterating over the subset.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to move an element into another element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Comment: The html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work perfectly :

```
$('.secondary-images .group2').detach().appendTo($('.secondary-images .group1'));
```

short and simple.

Comment: I will do that. Glad that you would help.

Comment: Can you please help me once more. Now i have a lot of extra stuff that wasn't in my old div do you know what that is. Thank You

Comment: `old div` as in `group1`?

Comment: No excuse me old div .group2. In gruop2 there was onle 2 filed__items but now are 4 extra items in group1

Comment: can you make a fiddle? so it'll be more easier to understand what's actually going wrong or possibly update your question.

Comment: Yes but excuse me what is a fiddle?? :)

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is an online platform to run your HTML, CSS & JS

Comment: Ok thank you i actually think i found out now. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Without .field__item after group2 it did'nt work but with it added an extra field__item that contains all of the stuff from group2.

Comment: It works now. I had an extra element without an image, then i used jquery to check if the div contained an image or not and then i removed the image. I will post my code.

Comment: I worked half of the way, but is was just what i needed, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".group1").append($(".group2").detach());
  });
</script>
```

Just before `</body>`

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/U6NwzpcYFojCrDkXWMRt?p=preview

Comment: Thank's for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
$('.secondary-images .group2 .field__item').detach().appendTo($('.secondary-images .group1'));
$('.secondary-images .field__item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('picture').length) {} else {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});­­­­
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- The mistake: Make sure the dom is available for manipulation. So this should work correctly:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var $element = $('.secondary-images > .group2').detach();
  $('.secondary-images > .group1').append($element);
});
```

2.- The way you want it to work: Due to the layout, the above code will make the whole `group2`div to appear inside the `group1` div, nesting it. I think you want to only put the content of it so here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.secondary-images > .group2 > .field__item').each(function() {
    $( this ).detach();
    $('.secondary-images > .group1').append( this );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secondary-images">
    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group1">
        <div class="field__item">a</div>
        <div class="field__item">b</div>
        <div class="field__item">c</div>
        <div class="field__item">d</div>
        <div class="field__item">e</div>
        <div class="field__item">f</div>
    </div>
    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group2">
        <div class="field__item">g</div>
        <div class="field__item">h</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- REFERENCE
<div class="secondary-images">
    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group1">
        <div class="field__item"></div>
        <div class="field__item"></div>
        <div class="field__item"></div>
        <div class="field__item"></div>
        <div class="field__item"></div>
        <div class="field__item"></div>
        <div class="field__item"></div>
        <div class="field__item"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/29/rd_page_secondary_image/da/full" class="group2">

    </div>
</div>
-->
```

This will detach and append every `field__item` from group2 and put it on group1, after that you can do whatever you like with group2, either remove it or leave it to fill with content later.

Comment: Why can't he start a variable with a $? We do it all the time, it helps to identify that the variable is referencing a jQuery object.

Comment: sorry, my mistake (wrong language), then the only mistake is that the dom isn't ready when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in one line. You can put in a function or event.

```
$('.secondary-images > .group2 > div').appendTo('.secondary-images > .group2');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
 var $element = $('.secondary-images > .group2 .field__item').detach();
 $('.secondary-images > .group1').append($element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$('.secondary-images .group2 .field__item').appendTo($('.secondary-images .group1'));
```