# insertAfter duplicates the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

the div gets inserted to the right place but it also keeps the div in the old position, so then there is two elements not sure why it is being cloned. Im editing woocommerce theme.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#place_order").insertAfter("tbody");
});
```

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet?

Comment: try detaching the element `$("#place_order").detach().insertAfter("tbody");`

Answer (score 1):

Use detach before insert after:

```
 $("#place_order").detach().insertAfter("tbody");
```

[some more informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Comment: even with this it gets copied, any other ideas?

Comment: @Zygimantas  I have the same problem with Ts & Cs div.  Did you ever solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var createdDiv= document.createElement('div');
  createdDiv.id = 'place_order';
  $(createdDiv).insertAfter("tbody");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody><tr><td>list</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```