# how to move an element to another parent using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi can anyone help me move class="title" to under class="thumbnail" but above span? Spent the wholeday working on this but no luck. I prefer in using jquery. I hope someone could help me sort this out. Thank you so much in advance.

```
<div class="aa">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#">Test 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <span>Hello</span>
            <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aa">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#">Test 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <span>Hello</span>        
            <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aa">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#">Test 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <span>Hello</span>        
            <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted the output to look like the below:

```
<div class="aa">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="title">
                <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            </div>
            <span>Hello</span>
            <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aa">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="title">
                <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            </div>
            <span>Hello</span>
            <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="aa">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="title">
                <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            </div>
            <span>Hello</span>
            <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$(".title").each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).next(".content").find(".thumbnail"));
});
```

This will move each of your `title` to the top of the corrosponding `thumbnail`

**Demo**

```js
$(".title").each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).next(".content").find(".thumbnail"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Test 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <span>Hello</span>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="aa">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Test 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <span>Hello</span>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="aa">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Test 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <span>Hello</span>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this question a dupe?

Comment: @RomeoSierra well, kinda, but it don't expain how to do it with multiple elements,  so thats why i posted the answer.

Comment: @RomeoSierra but nicely spottet by you, Thumbs up

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen you just saved my life. Thousand likes

Comment: @JustinDuran No problem, happy to help, if this solved your problem, please consider marking this as answer

Comment: sorry I am just new here, how to mark this solved or answer? Thanks

Comment: @JustinDuran Just to the left of my answer you see the up and down vote buttons, below that you should see a faded checkmark, just hit that.