# How to append Content using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendchild

I've got this below in jQuery, Where on a window width less than 1024px, I want to append ".moveThisContent" and move it to ".newLocation" what the best way to do this in Javascript is? Would it be to use `.appendChild`

```
if($(window).width() < 1024){
  $(".newLocation").append($(".moveThisContent"));
}
```

Comment: This is JavaScript? I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Does this not work?

Comment: Yes, `.appendChild()` is one possible option.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ / http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#append

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's another "remove jquery" / "convert this jquery to vanilla js for me" question

Comment: @evolutionxbox Almost. It's [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/), a macro language for  JavaScript.

Comment: Note that asking for "best way" is off topic as it's opinion based.  You're probably meaning to ask "how can I do this"

Comment: @traktor sorry I do understand what jQuery is. It's that the OP doesn't think it's JavaScript

Comment: More or less, append is short for element.classList.add and $(".className") is short for document.getElementByClassName

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS you might like to rethink that... .append(html) has nothing to do with classes

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#append

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS ah, it's not the "add" part, it's the "classList" part that's the issue

Comment: I was just trying to be specific to the question and not overwhelm the question asker for now.

Comment: Are you suggesting the use of parent.appendChild(el); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this i've used .appendChild and that does what i need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByClassName` and for set and get content you can use `innerHTML`

```js
const width  = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
if( width < 1024 ){
    document.getElementsByClassName('newLocation')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('moveThisContent')[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName('moveThisContent')[0].innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
.moveThisContent{color:blue;}
.newLocation{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="moveThisContent"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </div>
<div class="newLocation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the way of what you want to do**

> You can refer to this link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

> You can use media query in javascript for checking window width

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)").matches) {
  /* The viewport is less than, or equal to, 1024 pixels wide */
  var element = document.getElementByClassName("newLocation");
  element.classList.add("moveThisContent");
} else {
  /* The viewport is greater than 1024 pixels wide */
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to add a class name. Just move the content from one element to another.

Comment: moveThisContent already exists in the DOM.

Comment: // For Moving the content you can use following way from #myDiv1 to #myDiv2
 `$('#myDiv2').append( $('#myDiv1>p') );`

Comment: @neilnikkunilesh yes, that's what they're already doing - they want to move content without jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66886186/3825777, I thought I'd try and make things visually clear for visual learners.  I also wanted to make it clear what width we are talking about.  Please look at the console to see if the width you think you are talking about is less than or greater than 1024.

```js
$('#sWidth').text(window.screen.width);
$('#sHeight').text(window.screen.height);
$('#wWidth').text($(window).width());
$('#wHeight').text($(window).height());


const width  = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
console.log(width);
if( width < 1024 ){
    document.getElementsByClassName('newLocation')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('moveThisContent')[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName('moveThisContent')[0].innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
.moveThisContent{color:#111111;}
.newLocation{color:#777777;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Screen width: <span id="sWidth"></span><br>
Screen height: <span id="sHeight"></span><br>
Window width: <span id="wWidth"></span><br>
Window height: <span id="wHeight"></span><br>



<div class="moveThisContent"> This inner html content is inside a div with class name moveThisContent and in the css this has the color #111111.  I chose the number one not because I like the color 111111, but because I wanted to make it known that his is the first div in the HTML. The content of this div which is the text that you are reading should only move to the div with class name newLocation if the width of your screen is less than 1024 pixels.  The color of this other div is #777777. You will know the content moved if the text you are reading is grey.</div>
<div class="newLocation">The class name of this div is newLocation and the CSS hexidecimal color code for this div is 777777.  The content of this div will change to the content of the div before it if your screen width is less than 1024 pixels  </div>
```