# shift inner tags to parent tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've website https://www.totallifts.com.au/ whose menus are showing. There is **`+`** which is hiding extra menus.

[image]

I am trying to place hidden menu under new line such that it looks like this:

[image]

The code is this:

```
<ul id="top_menu" class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto text-right">
  <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....<li>
  <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
  <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....<li>
  <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
  <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....<li>
  <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
  <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....<li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown o_extra_menu_items">
<a role="button" href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle o-no-caret" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li class="mm-mega-menu">Vacuum & Pneumatics<li>
 <li class="mm-mega-menu">Industrial Towing<li>
 
</ul>


</li>

</ul>
```

My attempt:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").appendTo("#top_menu");
```

But it hides the entire menus under **+**
and by doing this:

`$("#top_menu").appendTo(".dropdown-menu");` does not show entire menu.

This one is closer to my requirement but i dont get why i m not getting the result.

[How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Can you show your expected result in html?

Comment: i ve already mentioned as well 2nd screen shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iMaM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append all `li` tag so try this one: `$(".dropdown-menu li").appendTo("#top_menu");`

```js
function append() {
            $(".dropdown-menu li").appendTo("#top_menu");
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="append()">click to append</button>

<ul id="top_menu" class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto text-right">
        <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
        <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
        <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
        <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
        <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
        <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
        <li class="nav-item  mm-mega-menu">....</li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown o_extra_menu_items">
            <a role="button" href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle o-no-caret" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="mm-mega-menu">Vacuum & Pneumatics</li>
                <li class="mm-mega-menu">Industrial Towing</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks you. I was missing just 'li' in my attempt.